# Does pointcloud_to_laserscan work for ASUS Xtion Pro Live

Tags: ros, pcl, asus-xtion-pro-live

[image: Rosanswers logo]

An inquiry, wish to know of any first hand experiences where [pointcloud_to_laser](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pointcloud_to_laserscan) has been successfully used with ASUS Xtion Pro Live ? Since Xtion and Kinect are both OpenNI devices hence in principle it should work out, however a first hand account may help my efforts.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62077/does-pointcloud_to_laserscan-work-for-asus-xtion-pro-live/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2013-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, pointcloud_to_laserscan and depthimage_to_laserscan work with Xtions and Kinects.  They also work with the new standalone Primesense devices.

For more information, see here:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/depthimage_to_laserscan

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2013-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-05-14**:
@Chad Rockey One more thing ! I am still using Electric, does pointcloud_to_laserscan work on it ?